# Real Analysis: Prove that $|\int_a^b f(x)dx-(b-a)f(a)|<\frac{1}{2}M(b-a)^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $|f'(x)|<M$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Prove that

$|\int_a^b f(x)dx-(b-a)f(a)|<\frac{1}{2}M(b-a)^2$.

What I have so far as thoughts:
I am thinking I will want to use the Mean Value Theorem, but I am lost as to how I need to start? Any hints would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 
$$
| \int_a ^b f(x) dx - (b-a)f(a)\,| 
= | \int_a ^b (f(x)-f(a) dx \,|
\leq  \int_a ^b |(f(x)-f(a)\,| dx
$$
By mean value theorem, we have
$$
|(f(x)-f(a)\,| \leq M |x-a| =M (x-a)
$$
Hence 
$$
| \int_a ^b f(x) dx - (b-a)f(a)\,| \leq \int_a ^b M (x-a) dx \leq \frac{1}{2} 
M (b-a)^2
$$

Comment: (Without lost the generality, we suppose first $b>a$.)

Comment: The very last inequality sign should be an equality sign.

Answer (score 1):

By the mean value theorem, if $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$, then $F(b)=\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$, $F(a)=0$, and 
 $$ \frac{F(b)-F(a)-(b-a)F'(a)}{(b-a)^2}=\frac{G(b)-G(a)}{t(b)-t(a)}=\frac{G'(c)}{t'(c)} $$ for some $c\in(a,b)$, where $G(x)=F(x)-F(a)-(x-a)F'(a)$, and $t(x)=(x-a)^2$, so $G'(x)=F'(x)-F'(a)=f(x)-f(a)$, and $t'(x)=2(x-a)$. That is, the fraction equals
 $$ \frac{f(c)-f(a)}{2(c-a)}=\frac{f'(d)}{2} $$
for some $d\in(a,c)$, by a new application of the mean value theorem. Putting this all together, we have 
 $$ \int_a^b f(x)\,dx -(b-a)f(a)=\frac{f'(d)}2(b-a)^2, $$ and using the given estimate for $|f'|$ gives the result.